# XMl formation in jersey with @rootelement

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jersey

I am using jersey RESt JAX-RS to develop rest web service. I would like to return the xml in the following format-

```
<RootChild>
<Child1>
<HFact>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
<d></d>
</HFact>

<PFact>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
<d></d>
</PFact>
</Child1>
....
</RootChild>
```

I am using@RootElement in each of the POJO class. but xml tree is not coming.

Comment: What does your JAX-RS method, object model, and current XML result look like?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Sorry, I was doing some mistake in proper configuration of Pojo Class. Due to this, I was not getting the xml/json. Now I solver this myself. Thank u very much for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Jersey RESTful web service to generate a response of a call in XML you need to declare that the call (method implementing the call) `@Produces({"application/xml"})`, that should be enough, providing you have your JAXB is correctly configured (the POJO you refer as response of the API call, and you build the response in the call).

Example of Jersey declaration:

```
@Path("/resource")
@Produces({ "application/xml"})
public class ResourceAPI{

    @GET
    @Path("/childs")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public GetChildsResp
            getChilds(){

        GetChildsResp response = new GetChildsResp();

        // build and populate response with all the Childs (from your DB)

        return response;

    }

}
```

Comment: I want the xml in this format and I am putting @RootElement in each POJO class. Bit it is not showing.

Comment: I have extended my response... add the POJO declaration so that we can help you further.